# ViewPager ScrollView not working

Tags: java, android

I'm implementing a viewpager inside a scrollview however the viewpager becomes malformed whenever it reaches the bottom edge of the screen making the scrollview not to work and the elements at bottom of viewpager not to be shown. This is my code:

```
1. Main Acitivity

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        ViewPager viewPager;
        ViewPager viewPager2;
        PagerAdapter adapter2;
        private static int currentPage = 0;
        private int[] IMAGES = {R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four};
        private ArrayList<Integer> IMAGESArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        private ScrollView scrollView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.landing_page);
            scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
            viewPager2 = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager3);
            // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
            adapter2 = new FirstViewPagerAdapter(TestActivity.this);
            // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
            viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter2);
            init();
        }

    private void init() {
        for(int i=0;i<IMAGES.length;i++)
            IMAGESArray.add(IMAGES[i]);
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            viewPager.setAdapter(new SecondViewPagerAdapter(TestActivity.this, IMAGESArray));
            CircleIndicator indicator = (CircleIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
            indicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
            // Auto start of viewpager
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (currentPage == IMAGES.length) {
                        currentPage = 0;
                    }
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
                }
            };
            Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
            swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler.post(Update);
                }
            }, 2500, 2500);
        }
}


2. The first view pager adapter

public class FirstViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ViewPager pager=null;
    private int images [] = {R.drawable.whiskey, R.drawable.vodka, R.drawable.whiskey, R.drawable.vodka, R.drawable.whiskey};
    public FirstViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, container, false);
        ImageView image1 = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image1.setImageResource(images[position]);

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position,
                            Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return(5);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return(view == object);
    }
}


3. The second view pager adapter

public class SecondViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Integer> images;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public SecondViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> images) {
        this.context = context;
        this.images=images;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
        View myImageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_item, view, false);
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) myImageLayout.findViewById(R.id.flag);
        myImage.setImageResource(images.get(position));
        view.addView(myImageLayout, 0);
        return myImageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }}


4. landing_page xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="#cccccc"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:vpi="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#cccccc"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
<me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
android:id="@+id/indicator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
app:ci_drawable="@drawable/myindicator"
vpi:snap="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/hdspiritsz"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"/>
<ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/hdextrasz"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/hdspiritsz"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"/>
<ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/hdextrasz"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#cccccc"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/pager3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/hdspiritsz"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"/>
<ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/hdextrasz"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

add android:fillViewport="true" to the ScrollView element.